# Just want to know if this rock, paper, scissors game looks good and if it can be improved more

Tags: javascript

// Prompt getting user input

```
var userInput = prompt("Choose rock(r), paper(p), or scissors(s)");
```

//Array with computer choices

```
var computerInput = ["r", "p", "s"];
```

//Randomizing array to get different values wit h each page refresh

```
var computerChoice = computerInput[Math.floor(Math.random() * computerInput.length)];
```

//Game code

```
if (userInput == "r" && computerChoice == "s") {
  console.log("You win!! Computer chose scissors");
} else if (userInput == "p" && computerChoice == "r") {
  console.log("You win!! Computer chose rock");
} else if (userInput == "s" && computerChoice == "p") {
  console.log("You win!! Computer chose paper");
} else if (userInput == computerChoice) {
  console.log("It\'s a draw!!");
} else {
  console.log("Computer wins!!");
}
```

Comment: Maybe tell the player what the computer chose if the player loses?

Comment: This question belongs to https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Many possible improvements: input validation (current the computer wins if you enter a wrong letter, or whole word), multiple rounds of playing, nicer user interface (not a mix of prompt modals and log messages), …